# Can not delete Magento attribute value in admin

Tags: magento, attributes

Unexplainably, at least 13.000 products (of the 60.000) recieved two attribute values on the front-end website which do not apply to the product.

So in Magento admin, we try to remove the attribute value of the attribute, but after saving, it's still there in Magento (and on the website). We recieve no error message on saving the attribute, only the message "attribute is saved". But after returning to the values tab of the attribute, the 'deleted' value is still there.

What can be wrong?

Comment: did you reindex all data in system>index managment? Sometimes it store "old| data

Comment: Yes, we tried this. We selected all the options in Index Management en re-indexed it all (takes a couple of hours in our store). Somehow Magento does not save the attribute correctly. 
It's still a puzzle to us on how the wrong attribute value was added to 13.000 products, but deleting them is even harder.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

you need to identify the attribute ids for all global attributes then delete all the values from the `catalog_product_entity_*` tables that have the attribute id one of those identified above and the store id field not zero.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` 
WHERE
   store_id <> 0 AND
   attribute_id IN (
           SELECT attribute_id 
           FROM catalog_eav_attribute 
           WHERE is_global = 1

   )
```

Do the same for the tables `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime`, `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.

Rebuild your indexes when your are done.

Note: The select from `catalog_eav_attribute` in the way I wrote it will give you attribute ids for the global category attributes also, but that's not important since in the product tables you don't have category attributes references.

Also, before trying this, backup your database in case I missed something.

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42763/6501
Thanks to: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius